# Override Alfresco pickerresults.lib.ftl

Tags: alfresco, freemarker

I've found a bug in [pickerresults.lib.ftl](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/e0c6c4088320113db82e16ca5e3261aa321ec26d/projects/remote-api/config/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/forms/pickerresults.lib.ftl) that i have already [reported](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-21286)

Briefly: if the user does not have the permission on a file parent, the line

> [<#if row.item.parent??>"parentName": "${row.item.parent.name!""}",](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition/blob/e0c6c4088320113db82e16ca5e3261aa321ec26d/projects/remote-api/config/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/forms/pickerresults.lib.ftl#L35)

will fail, failing the entire script (and the user can't see any file)

So, waiting for the bug being resolved i need to patch this. I'd like to override the macro "pickerResultsJSON" defined in the file removong the line or putting a string value in place of "${row.item.parent.name!""}" that cause the exception

I have no idea of how to redefine the macro and where to place the file inside my amp. Can someone help me?

**UPDATE**

I'm using the [Alfresck SDK 2.0](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/alfresco-sdk-intro.html) and my project structure is:

[image: Project Structure]

I've tryed to put a file "custom-pickerresults.lib.ftl" with the following content (as suggested by sev) but it does not seem to be the right position. Or should i "register" it in some way?

```
<#macro pickerResultsJSON results>
    <#-- new code here -->
</#macro>
<#global pickerResultsJSON = pickerResultsJSON />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to sev, he pointed me the right way.

I realized that `pickerresults.lib.ftl` is used by the webservice `pickerchildren.get.desc.xml` and `pickerchildren.post.desc.xml`so, the solution is to copy the web service definition and files along with the library in

```
/alfresco-myamp-repo/src/main/amp/config/alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/com/my/repository/forms/
```

(`repository/forms/` just becouse the original files are inside `config/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/forms/` but any other folder under `/alfresco-myamp-repo/src/main/amp/config/alfresco/extension` shuld do)

and change the library like this:

```
                ...
                "type": "${row.item.typeShort}",
                "parentType": "${row.item.parentTypeShort!""}",
<#-- from here -->
                <#attempt>
                    <#if row.item.parent??>"parentName": "${row.item.parent.name!""}",</#if>
                <#recover>
                    "parentName": "<unknown>",
                </#attempt>
<#-- to here -->
                "isContainer": ${row.item.isContainer?string},
                <#if row.container??>"container": "${row.container!""}",</#if>
                ...
```

This way even if the user has not the permissions to read the parent's name the template can complete without errors (i don't know if the value "unknown" in place of the parent name can cause any troubles, but i did not notice nothing right now)

Answer (score 2):

Since macros are just variables, you might be able to do something like this:

```
<#macro pickerResultsJSON>
    <#-- new code here -->
</#macro>
<#global pickerResultsJSON = pickerResultsJSON />
```

As to where you would put that... you could put it in any file that is included globally on your project.  It might require a little trial and error since I'm not sure what your project structure is.

Comment: thanks you, please take a look at my update in the first post

Comment: You'll need to import or include the file. Do you have any files in your project that have like `<#import "x.ftl" as y>` or `<#include "x.ftl">`?